# Using Github to create a webpage but it returns a 404 error

Tags: github

Am trying to test out hosting a website from Github using Github pages.I created a skeleton website using Jekyll and uploaded it into a .github.io repository:

https://github.com/themallardcomplexion/themallardcomplexion.github.io

I then enabled github pages from the setting.

So right now if I go to: themallardcomplexion.github.io I should be able to see the Jekyll site. However all I get is a 404 error...

I know its not an index issue as I have an index.md file in my repository. I've enabled github pages so what am I doing wrong? I have tried searching for the problem online but none of the solutions seem applicable..

Thanks internet people

Comment: Try git checkout -b gh-pages and then push that branch to github with git push origin gh-pages

Comment: under Settings -> Git hub pages -> Source it says that my page is being built from the master branch and that User pages must be built from the master branch i.e. i cant change branches to the new one you suggested I create..

Comment: I think it is just because you didn't wait for [some time](https://guides.github.com/features/pages/). "This can take up to 10 minutes."

Comment: Nah I waited like two days, I even tried to push from my local repository to the online one again. Still didnt work. I ended up just deleting the repository and recreating it with the same files. That worked and it happened pretty much instantly (i,e, i didnt even have to wait 10 minutes!)

Answer (score 0):

I deleted everything and created a new repository. Seems to be working now. Dont know what the problem was but at least its working..